# Centering TextBlock text inside border element

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, border, textblock

I am playing around with silverlight - specifically Silverlight for windows phone. I would like to have a textblock inside a border element. I want the textblock to fill up the entire border element. I would also like the text inside the textblock to the centered within the textblock - both vertical and horizontal.

The problem that I am encountering is that if I set the horizontal and vertical alignment of the textblock to center, then the textblock resizes to the size of the text, hence the textblock does not fill up all the available room inside the border. If I set the horizontal and vertical alignment properties of textblock to stretch, I get the textblock to expand to fill up the border, but the textblock text is not centered anymore. I think I can use padding to center the text, but this does not give a precise result as the length of the text can vary.

The reason why I would like to have the textblock within a border in the first place is because Silverlight for Windows Phone does not provide a background property for textblock. I use the border to provide a background color.

In short, is there any way to center the text in a textblock, when the textblock is inside a border element and the textblock must stretch to fill the border.

Below is the code that I have so far.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock Name="textBlockA1" Text="Center Me!" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"            
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to center or stretch anything. I assume you will eventually put this `Border` to a `Grid`, so just set the `Grid`'s column and row to auto and the `Border` will resize itself based on the size of the `TextBlock`.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"> 
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockA1" Text="Center Me!"/> 
        </Border> 
    </Grid>
```

**UPDATE**

I don't understand why someone would downvoted this. This is definitely a good way to add a `Background` color to a `TextBlock`. It's like you are filling the `Grid`'s cells with the `Border`'s background color. See below example.

[image]

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> 
            <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition/> 
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> 
            <RowDefinition Height="12"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="12" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/> 
        </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <Border Background="#FFBC7C0A">  
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockA1" Text="Center Me!" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>  
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FFBC7C0A" Grid.Row="2">  
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockA2" Text="Center Me!" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>  
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FFBC7C0A" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">  
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockA3" Text="This is a longer text" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>  
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FFBC7C0A" Grid.Column="3">  
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockA4" Text="Short" Foreground="White" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>  
        </Border>
        <Border Background="#FFBC7C0A" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left">  
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockA5" Text="Center Me!" Foreground="White" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>  
        </Border>  
    </Grid>
```

Also, if you want a left or right margin on the `TextBlock` you can either apply a style to the `TextBlock` (e.g. `PhoneTextNormalStyle`) or give a padding to the `Border`.

Comment: Why would this resize the TextBlock differently? It would just resize the first column/row, moving the TextBlock and Border to top/left of the grid...

Comment: What he really wants is not resizing the `TextBlock`'s size, he's just not sure why the `Border` doesn't just fit the size of the `TextBlock`. Putting them into a `Grid` would be one obvious solution.

Comment: I do not want to resize the textblock. The textblock needs to have a fixed size. All I want is for the text within the textblock to be centered, while the textblock stretches to fill its' container, which is border element in this case.

Comment: Isn't my answer what you want to achieve?

Comment: What is it that centralize the text? Is it the style or the fact that you are using a grid?

Comment: @TomasJansson It looks like it's centered but it's actually not. The styles have a left and right margin of 12, that's why it looks like it's centered. If you remove `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` in the `Border`, you need to add `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` to the inner `TextBlock` to make it centered.

Answer (score 1):

If center alignment does not do it for you and you want to stretch the text to use up more space you can either use the FontSize property and choose a bigger font or use a ViewBox:

```
<Border
    BorderBrush="Red"
    BorderThickness="2"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0">
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock
            Name="textBlockA1"
            Text="Center Me!"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Viewbox>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried using the Viewbox control as you suggested. The viewbox centers the text, but the downside is that it changes the size of the font. I will have many such textblocks in my UI that display different text, and if I used viewbox, it looks like I will have different font sizes depending on the length of the text. This will not look good on the UI.

Comment: You mentioned that when you make the TextBlock centered with Horizontal/Vertical-Alignment set to Center - you are not using the entire available space. On the other hand - you said you want the TextBlock to be centered in its container and it should stretch... I am a bit stumped. The TextBlock will only ever be the size of its text and it would not matter if it were bigger because it in itself does not have any background brush or border. Perhaps all you need is the TextBlock.TextAlignment property set to Center?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe I do not understand the textblock well. I did not know that the textblock will always be the size of its' text. I was under the impression the textblock element could be a different size than the text it holds. In my app, I need to have about 20 equally sizes controls that the user can press to make a selection. It would look visually nice if the text within these controls were all centered in relation to the control. So then I would be better off using a button than a textblock?

Comment: If you need a row or a column of TextBlocks that each take up the same amount of space - you can put them in a grid with star-height/width row/column definitions (eg. <RowDefition Height="*"/>) or you can give them specific dimensions using Width and Height so each will occupy the same amount of space. If you need backgrounds - you would also put them inside of a <Border/> or in front of a <Rectangle/>, all while making sure to set their Horizontal/Vertical Alignment is set to Center.